# Prevent shrinking of background image of a scroll view when keypad is opened

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I have a scroll view which has a background image. When the keypad is opened, the image gets shrunk. When the keypad is closed, it expands again. How to stop this shrinking from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add this to your manifset file between your related activity tags

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

**adjustPan** means ; your activity will not be resized to fit new sizes when keyboard opened, and it will keep old form

Comment: I had keyboard popup problem while using this, I just replaced `stateVisible` to `stateHidden` that just worked the way i want. Anyway thank you.